# Trouble with Cloudflare Tunnel on SageMaker: Cannot Establish Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-sagemaker

I'm attempting to bring my host online using Cloudflare Tunnel on SageMaker, aiming for the address 0.0.0.0:7860. I've followed the Cloudflare documentation for setting up a tunnel, but I'm encountering difficulties establishing the connection.

Here's the output I'm receiving after
`!/home/studio-lab-user/cloudflared tunnel --url http://0.0.0.0:7860`
:

```
2024-01-30T18:17:21Z INF Thank you for trying Cloudflare Tunnel. Doing so, without a Cloudflare account, is a quick way to experiment and try it out. However, be aware that these account-less Tunnels have no uptime guarantee. If you intend to use Tunnels in production you should use a pre-created named tunnel by following: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps
2024-01-30T18:17:21Z INF Requesting new quick Tunnel on trycloudflare.com...
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF |  Your quick Tunnel has been created! Visit it at (it may take some time to be reachable):  |
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF |  https://sync-dip-uniprotkb-dayton.trycloudflare.com                                       |
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /etc/cloudflared /usr/local/etc/cloudflared]
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Version 2024.1.5
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.21.5, GoArch: amd64
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Settings: map[ha-connections:1 protocol:quic url:http://0.0.0.0:7860]
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF cloudflared will not automatically update when run from the shell. To enable auto-updates, run cloudflared as a service: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/run-tunnel/as-a-service/
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Generated Connector ID: 8e966e6f-5266-4cf8-923b-089d30788d44
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Initial protocol quic
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF ICMP proxy will use 169.254.255.2 as source for IPv4
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF ICMP proxy will use :: as source for IPv6
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z WRN The user running cloudflared process has a GID (group ID) that is not within ping_group_range. You might need to add that user to a group within that range, or instead update the range to encompass a group the user is already in by modifying /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range. Otherwise cloudflared will not be able to ping this network error="Group ID 100 is not between ping group 65534 to 65534"
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z WRN ICMP proxy feature is disabled error="cannot create ICMPv4 proxy: Group ID 100 is not between ping group 65534 to 65534 nor ICMPv6 proxy: socket: permission denied"
2024-01-30T18:17:22Z INF Starting metrics server on 127.0.0.1:40995/metrics
2024/01/30 18:17:22 failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size (was: 208 kiB, wanted: 2048 kiB, got: 416 kiB). See https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Buffer-Sizes for details.
2024-01-30T18:17:27Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.192.107
2024-01-30T18:17:27Z INF Retrying connection in up to 2s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.192.107
2024-01-30T18:17:33Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.193
2024-01-30T18:17:33Z INF Retrying connection in up to 4s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.193
2024-01-30T18:17:38Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.113
2024-01-30T18:17:38Z INF Retrying connection in up to 8s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.113
2024-01-30T18:17:45Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.192.27
2024-01-30T18:17:45Z INF Retrying connection in up to 16s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.192.27
^C
2024-01-30T18:17:46Z INF Initiating graceful shutdown due to signal interrupt ...
2024-01-30T18:17:46Z INF Tunnel server stopped
2024-01-30T18:17:46Z INF Metrics server stopped
```

It seems that the tunnel creation is successful, but I encounter issues with establishing the connection. Specifically, I receive repeated timeout errors with no recent network activity when attempting to dial to various IPs.

I've checked my configuration and followed the provided troubleshooting steps, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Can someone help me understand what might be causing these connection problems and how I can address them effectively?

Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide.

- Checked my Cloudflare Tunnel configuration for any errors.
- Verified that my SageMaker instance is correctly configured to accept incoming connections on port 7860.
- Ensured that there are no firewall restrictions blocking outbound connections.
- Reviewed Cloudflare's documentation and community forums for similar issues but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by creating a CloudFlare tunnel from StudioLab?

Comment: Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab is designed for aspiring data scientists, engineers, scientists, teachers, and students interested in learning or experimenting with data science, scientific computing, machine learning, and deep learning using Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @MarcKarp I'm trying to achieve the ability to share and view my webpage from various devices. I'm learning to develop web pages independently, experimenting with what I find online. While the CloudFlare tunnel method works on my computer, it's not functioning on SageMaker. I've used Ngrok, but it quickly hits the 1GB monthly limit per token due to the heavy data usage of my webpage.
Edit: also tried zrok, but so limited